# convert php script to c#

Tags: c#, php

i want to connect my site(mvc5) to payeer payment proccessor .i read payeers document but all script of document is in php .please help me to convert this script to c#.

```
<?php if (!in_array($_SER VER['REMOTE_AD DR'], array('185.71.65.92', '185.71.65.189','149.202.17.210'))) return; if isset($_POST['m_operation_id']) && isset($_POST['m_sign'])){ $m_key = 'Your secret key';$arHash = array($_POST['m_operation_id'],$_POST['m_operation_ps'],$_POST['m_operation_date'],$_POST['m_operation_pay_date'],$_POST['m_shop'],$_POST['m_orderid'],$_POST['m_amount'],$_POST['m_curr'],$_POST['m_desc'],$_POST['m_status']);if isset($_POST['m_params'])){$arHash[] = $_POST['m_params'];}$arHash[] = $m_key;$sign_hash = strtoupper(hash('sha256', implode(':', $arHash)));if $_POST['m_sign'] == $sign_hash && $_POST['m_status'] == 'success'){exit($_POST['m_orderid'].'|success');}exit($_POST['m_orderid'].'|error');}?>
```

Comment: One option is to use model binding/validation and linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_AD DR'], array('185.71.65.92', '185.71.65.189','149.202.17.210'))) return;
```

in this line code checks if the client address is in white list, if it is not in white list so block request, you can do this in c# using this code:

```
string[] whiteListIps = new string[]{'185.71.65.92', '185.71.65.189','149.202.17.210'};
var clientIp = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if(!whiteListIps.Contains(clientIp))
     return Redirect("/UnAuthorized");
```

in the next line you should check if **m_operation_id** and **m_sign** exists in Request.Body

the below is in php:

```
if isset($_POST['m_operation_id']) && isset($_POST['m_sign']))
```

in c#:

```
 if(Request.Form["m_operation_id"] != null && Request.Form("m_sign") != null)
```

**$m_key** and **$arHash** just are variables that declared based on posted values and a key that will used in **SHA256** algorithm to decode message to ensure if received message hash is equal with parameters value